# Is there any corda 4.1 docker container available?

Tags: docker-compose, corda

Is there any corda 4.1 docker container available?

Tried some sample repositories available in Github, but it deals with Corda version 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is docker image available for Corda 4+.

Here is the Link: https://hub.docker.com/r/corda/corda-zulu-4.1